# Run Unit Test Before Launch

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have just created my first unit test as part of an android project. I followed the guide found [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support).

Now I would like to include all unit tests in the "test" package before the app is launched to the phone. How would I include this in the gradle file?